# TeamCity doesn't compile the Visual Studio MS Test Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild, teamcity, teamcity-7.0

I have several MS Test project in my solution, but in build server (TeamCity 7.1), I can't compile them. the exception is saying ...'VisualStudio' namesapce does not exist...

I copied the VisualStudio Tools into the Build server GAC, but still no luck!

Comment: What is the full error message you're facing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in your test projects. you're referencing to some assemblies which haven't been deployed to the Build Server(TeamCity). Also you cannot do that by simply copy and paste to GAC or working directory.

The best and easiest way to do that is installing [**Visual studio 2010 Agents**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1334) in the build server.
It's free and it can be downloaded from MS web site. By installing the agents, it will install all the required libraries for compiling and even running the MSTest projects.

Comment: Thanks, it's Compiling now , PHEW!